# hostname -f and socket.getfqdn() returning different

Tags: python, linux, networking, centos, centos7

I am using CentOS 7 in VMVirtualbox in Windows 10. In `/etc/hosts` file, I have added the ipaddress of Windows PC     `abc.def.xyz.abc`
and changed `hostname` to `abc.def.xyz.abc`.

But when I run the following commands, the output is different:

```
$ python -c 'import socket;print socket.gethostname()'
abc.def.xyz 
$ python -c 'import socket;print socket.getfqdn()' 
windows-xzv.abcdomain.com
$ hostname -f
abc.def.xyz
$ python -c 'import platform;print platform.node()' 
abc.def.xyz
```

Comment: Systemd broke that portion of networking. Also see [Issue 6369, systemd does not honor fully qualified domain names](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6369).

Comment: Its working now, I changed the order in /etc/nsswitch.conf put files infront of dns